# Como alinhar o texto do JButton a esquerda do icone?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Preciso alinhar o texto do `JButton` a esquerda do ícone como eu faço?

Tentei usar o método

```
 button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

mas este método não alinha o texto do jeito que eu quero.

Está ficando igual o primeiro mas  quero que fique igual o segundo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está um código genérico para criar o botão:

```
  public void genericMethod(){
          JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setText("GenericButton");
        button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/nextnext.png")));
        button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String s[]) {
     new NewClass().genericMethod();

    }
```

O retorno do código acima fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A resposta você já deu na pergunta, é justamente o `button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);` voce nem ta usando isso no codigo.

Comment: com este método o ícone continua a  esquerda  mesmo se  eu mudar  o parâmetro para RIGHT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
jButton.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);          
jButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);                
jButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

Fonte: [Changing Icon Position On Jbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36821976/5524514)

---

Fiz uns testes aqui e foi preciso apenas a linha abaixo para fazer com que a seta fique a direita do texto. Faça o teste você mesmo, substituindo o caminho dos dois botões do código abaixo e apontando para seu icone:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JButtonAlinhaTextIconTest {

    public void genericMethod() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton button1 = new JButton();
        JButton button2 = new JButton();

        button1.setText("button1");
        button2.setText("button2");

        try {
            button1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/arrow-right-black.png"))));
            button2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/arrow-right-black.png"))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        button1.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new JButtonAlinhaTextIconTest().genericMethod());
    }
}
```

Somente o `button1` foi aplicado a configuração e somente ele alinhou o icone a esquerda. Veja o resultado que obtive:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olha, meu código está igual  o da pergunta  mas está deixando o icone a esquerda mesmo assim.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.